# How to program SoC chips like CC2541F128RHAT

Tags: microcontroller, embedded, bluetooth, bluetooth-low-energy, soc

I am working on a BLE project. As per initial research, decided to use the cc2541 chip as BLE module. I have found one [here](http://in.element14.com/texas-instruments/cc2541f128rhat/ic-soc-bluetooth-2-4ghz-40vqfn/dp/2281643?st=cc2541). As per the datasheet, it shows it contains BLE and MCU. I need to program the MCU for accessing the GPIO pins. Can I connect a USB-TTL converter and program SoC like this or is it requires special development kits for development.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I use TI's cc2541 BLE as micro controller to perform operations/ processing instead of ATmega328P AU to save cost?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/209059/can-i-use-tis-cc2541-ble-as-micro-controller-to-perform-operations-processing)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Official tools are listed at TI's site http://www.ti.com/product/CC2541/toolssoftware

You need an 8051 toolchain (compiler and friends). You also need a programmer like the CC-DEBUGGER. There may be some software that can bit-bang an FTDI chip to program the CC2541.

Development kit **is** the easiest option to get started with a new chip.

Comment: And personally I find Cortex-M Bluetooth chips easier to work with as you can use popular toolchains and standard ARM debug probes (like J-Link). Have a look at Nordic Semi and Silicon Labs for example.